# want to change an Inset in a gridbag layout dynamically

Tags: java, swing

I have a gridbag layout where I initialize an gbc.insets = Insets(0,0,0,); 
Later I want to resize this inset when some action happens. 
I've tried changing the value and then doing a repaint() but that does not work?
What do I need to do? Thank you very much!

```
class myGraph {

    private Insets myInsets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

    ...
    gbc.insets = myInsets; // setting Gridbag constraints.



    Action Listener {

        ............... 
        myInsets.top =30;
        myInsets.bottom =40;
        myGraph.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"What do I need to do???????????????"* 1st up, fix that sticky '?' key.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the GridBagLayout:

```
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
...
layout.setConstraints(myComponent, anotherConstraint);
// do this for all the components you want to update
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

GridBagLayout clones your constraints when you add components, so you need to tell the LayoutManager that you want to change those constraints. Simply modifying the consraints value will have absolutely no effect.

Btw, repaint() is just to perform "painting" operations, not layout. Use revalidate() instead.

Comment: please not sure if GBC required or not panel.repaint();, why to save important code line :-)

Comment: @mKorbel sorry, you got me lost there. I don't understand what you are saying (although I'm pretty sure you are correct ;)-). I used the same technique in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575450/java-forcing-a-component-to-fill-up-the-entire-row-in-a-gridlayout/10575616#10575616) and it works quite nicely.

Comment: simple and short answer, (please) never to use revalidate without repaint, for testing code doesn't matter ...

Comment: @mKorbel I think it can work without it. Is it really considered as a "Good practice" to always call repaint() after revalidate()? And Is it considered "Evil practice" not to do so? This is just to extend my knowledge.

Comment: If I just want to change one constraint can I do that or do I have to redo all of my other constraits I had previously also. That would seem to be a lot of code. I see that example and there seems like there should be an easy way to update just one constraint.

Comment: @user565660 No you only need to update the constraints that are modified, the other ones will remain.

Comment: @mKorbel If you created your component/layout like this: ```JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout())``` do you know a way to get the GridBagLayout object from ```p``` and use the ```setConstraints()``` method? Or, perhaps just any way to update constraints with the expression I provided.